# Why does my texture look like this

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing, node-editor

Hey guys im new to blender, and for some reason my roughness map shows up like this strippy sort of image....

(i tried to change the cordinates but still cant get it to work properly....

The map its a puddle texture !!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Right now, I think that your image looks quite good, if you went for some sort of brushed metal. Other than that -  it's understandably very hard to give an answer to your question without knowing what we are looking at or what you expect to see. Please use the edit link below your question and add sufficient information.

Comment: @kay777 Ctrl+A > Apply Scale on the object.

Comment: @cegaton Puddle map / noise map

Comment: i think you have to reunwrap your object

Comment: It's probably your Mapping Node. Can you pack your textures into your .blend and post it? [Blend Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)